# Migrating maven service to ant service

Tags: maven, ant, liferay, liferay-6

I'm working on a liferay portlet developed by another contractor. The project was designed in maven, with all the service classes (service-builder) in a seperate bundle. So when the project is called foo, there are projects like:

- foo-portlet
- foo-service

  - foo-service-portlet
  - foo-service-portlet-service

I don't really understand why the services are splitted like that. And why they aren't part of foo-portlet.

The `service.xml` is located in `foo-service-portlet/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. There's no `build.xml` so running service-builder using ant won't work.

Now, we're facing some troubles because of https://issues.liferay.com/browse/MAVEN-37 and I'd like to turn the services into an ant project.

I thought about:

1. Creating another portlet using the plugins-sdk
2. Copying the old `service.xml` and overriding the new one
3. Running service-builder with ant
4. Copying the old impl classes and overriding the new ones
5. Rerunning the service builder using ant

But what will hapen when I deploy the new portlet? Will liferay realize that the tables defined are already there? The old code is already in production and has a lot of data which may not be lost!

Thanks in advance, Fabi.

Btw., still using liferay 6.1.20 EE.

Comment: What is the liferay version that you are using, The liferay issue been fixed for maven plugin version 6.1.30, I guess.

Comment: Also, the design of using foo-service-portlet and foo-service-portlet-service is good when you try to reuse same service .jar in multiple portlets. In this approach foo-service-portlet-service stores its .jar in repository and can be referenced by another portlet using dependency.

Comment: I'm using liferay 6.1.20 and cannot update, because of restrictions by the client. Thanks for clarifying the service seperation.